# How to correct a VBA Reverse For Loop Syntax Error with Step - 1

Tags: excel, vba

Morning,

I'm looking to loop through a column in one open workbook and if a date is older than 2 years I want to first copy that entire row to a second workbook I have open and then delete that row that has been copied.

I've read that I need to start at the bottom of the data I want to delete rows from to get it to work correctly. I've tried including .Row Step -1 but it produces a syntax error and I also tried a few other variations from Google that resulted in a similar syntax error.

Any help in amending my below code to just handle the deletion of the rows correctly would be greatly appreciated. It copies across the rows correctly top down

```
Sub TestArchive()
Dim sh As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range, sh2 As Worksheet, lr2 As Long, c As Range
Set sh = Sheets("DUP_ALL") 'Edit sheet name
'Set sh2 = Sheets("Archive") 'Edit Sheet name
lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh.Range("C2:C" & lr)

For Each c In rng
    If IsDate(c.Value) Then
        If c.Value < Date - 456 Then
            lr2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            c.EntireRow.Copy sh2.Range("A" & lr2)
            End If
        End If
    Next
For Each c In rng
    If IsDate(c.Value) Then
        If c.Value < Date - 456 Then
            lr1 = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step - 1
            c.EntireRow.Delete sh.Range("A" & lr1)
           End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Step` relates to the `For` loop, to indicate the direction of looping. To go backwards it's easier to use a counter rather than a range.

You can do it thus, and note do not need both loops.

```
Sub TestArchive()

Dim sh As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range, sh2 As Worksheet, lr2 As Long, c As Range
Set sh = Sheets("DUP_ALL") 'Edit sheet name
'Set sh2 = Sheets("Archive") 'Edit Sheet name
lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh.Range("C2:C" & lr)
Dim r As Long

For r = rng.Count To 1 Step -1
    If IsDate(rng(r).Value) Then
        If rng(r).Value < Date - 456 Then
            lr2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            rng(r).EntireRow.Copy sh2.Range("A" & lr2)
            rng(r).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the above. It worked once I removed the first "Next" you've put as it seemed to want an additional "For" It worked exactly as required though. Thanks for the explanation as to what I was doing wrong as well. When I read your answer it makes perfect sense as to why it wasn't working for me and what I need to do in the future if I want to do a reverse loop

Answer (score 0):

`Step -1` should be included in the loop statement to specify the direction of the loops (and if iterations should be skipped, such as with `Step 2`)

What you have done is added `Step -1` to the line which populates a variable with the last filled row in a column. That results in nonsense code.

An example of a correct loop would look like

```
With Sheet1
    'determine the last row in col A in the sheet with codename Sheet1
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Commence the loop. Start i at LRow and end at the second row, going backwards  
    For i = LRow To 2 Step - 1

        'Check if the cell's value in col B of row i is "test"
        If .Cells(i, "B").Value = "test" Then 'an alternative to Cells is .Range("B" & i)
            'delete the row with rownumber i
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
```